# pandas how to use groupby with loc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
data = {'fruit': ['pear','pear','banana', 'pear', 'pear','apple', 'melon', 'cherry','cherry'],
'country': ['russia','usa', 'russia', 'russia','ghana','russia', 'russia', 'albania','andorra'],
'id': ['011','011','011', '011', '011','011', '6', '6','6'],
'month': ['march','march', 'november', 'march', 'january','january', 'march', 'january','july']       
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['fruit','country', 'id', 'month'])
```

[image]

I want to drop contiguous duplicates in each group by `'id'`.
I have the

```
cols = ["fruit"]
de_dup = a[cols].loc[(df[cols].shift() != df[cols]).any(axis=1)]
```

but without using groupby.
How do i can run it with `groupby('id')`, can anyone see the problem?

Output dataframe:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid using groupby, you can simply compare both "id" and "fruit" at the same time like so:

```
subset = df[["id", "fruit"]]

# marks all contiguous repeats of "id" and "fruit" as True
contiguous_duplicates = (subset == subset.shift()).all(axis=1)
new_df = df.loc[~contiguous_duplicates, :]

print(new_df)
    fruit  country   id     month
0    pear   russia  011     march
2  banana   russia  011  november
3    pear   russia  011     march
5   apple   russia  011   january
6   melon   russia    6     march
7  cherry  albania    6   january
```

---

Explanation:

- `subset = df[["id", "fruit"]]` all we're doing here is grabbing all of the relevant columns we want to compare

```
>>> print(subset)
    id   fruit
0  011    pear
1  011    pear
2  011  banana
3  011    pear
4  011    pear
5  011   apple
6    6   melon
7    6  cherry
8    6  cherry
```

- `(subset == subset.shift())` All this is doing is shifting all of the rows down one and comparing it back to the original subset. When we compare them, it returns us a boolean dataframe (with the same size as `subset`) whose True/False values correspond whether the value is the same as the previous value from the same row/column.

```
      id  fruit
0  False  False
1   True   True
2   True  False
3   True  False
4   True   True
5   True  False
6  False  False
7   True  False
8   True   True
```

In the above frame, you can see we've compared every value of the shifted subset to the original subset. If a value is True that means it is the same as the value in the previous row. Note the "id" column has a lot of `True` values because of the repeated "id" values.

- `.all(axis=1)` now that we have a boolean dataframe, we want to check if entire rows are `True` if they are, that means this entire row is the same as the previous row in the dataframe. These are the rows we want to drop since they are "contiguous repeats".

```
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
6    False
7    False
8     True
dtype: bool
```

Now this `Series` represents where the previous boolean dataframe was True across an entire row. Since these are the rows we want to drop (and not keep), we will need to flip this boolean `Series` which can be done with the tilde `~` operator:

- `df.loc[~contiguous_duplicates, :]` inverts the aforementioned boolean `Series` and uses it to select rows from the original dataframe.

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you give me a short explanation what happens in contiguous_duplicates = (subset == subset.shift()).all(axis=1)?

Comment: Just added an explanation, let me know if something still doesn't make sense or needs further explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Another way without groupby:

```
df.assign(dupkey=(df[cols].shift() != df[cols]).cumsum()).drop_duplicates('dupkey')
```

Output:

```
    fruit  country   id     month  dupkey
0    pear   russia  011     march       1
2  banana   russia  011  november       2
3    pear   russia  011     march       3
5   apple   russia  011   january       4
6   melon   russia    6     march       5
7  cherry  albania    6   january       6
```

---

And with groupby

```
df.groupby((df[cols].shift() != df[cols]).cumsum().squeeze(), as_index=False).first()
```

Output:

```
    fruit  country   id     month
0    pear   russia  011     march
1  banana   russia  011  november
2    pear   russia  011     march
3   apple   russia  011   january
4   melon   russia    6     march
5  cherry  albania    6   january
```

Comment: Can you give me a desicion, where explicity written groupby('id')?